# ResponseEntityExceptionHandler in SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have created this class to manage the exceptions

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    public RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    // API

    // 400
...
}
```

But when I try to use it in 1 of my method :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getUsers", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@ExceptionHandler({RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class })
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> testErrors(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader) {

...

}
```

I got this compilation error :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class to Class>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [docs for `@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) you will see that it is used to mark a method to handle exception(s). Therefore you have to specify which exception(s) it can handle (e.g. `@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)` or `@ExceptionHandler({MyException.class, MyOtherException.class})`). When such an exception occurs in your controller this method gets invoked.

`@ControllerAdvice` makes the methods defined in the class available to all your controllers.

I don't know what you want to do, but since you extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in the `@ControllerAdvice` class, you could just delete the `@ExceptionHandler annotation`:

```
@GetMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> testErrors(...) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to handle specific exceptions on your own, you can do it like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMyException() {
        ...
    }

}

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(...)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> testErrors(...) {
        throw new MyException();
    }

}
```

Now `handleException()` will be called when an error occurs in `testErrors()`.

If you want to handle exceptions only in one controller you can do this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping(...)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> testErrors(...) {
        throw new MyException();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMyException() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice way of explaining how this works, but kinda misses the point of the OP's original question, which is why their own method was not working correctly (i.e the class mismatch problem).

Answer (score 1):

It's expected for this not to work correctly.

You're attempting to pass in the `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` as the arguments of the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation in your test method. This is wrong, as this annotation accepts the type of the exception that gets intercepted.

Also in general it seems that the placement of your `@ExceptionHandler` annotation seems to be wrong. This are placed within method that reside in the actual exception handling class.

I suggest you have a good read on the way Spring handles exceptions in that manner.

Have a look at this piece of documentation: [exception handling in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).